# PHP combine 2 arrays and include to a 3rd array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, each

I have 2 given arrys:

Array one (which are the "Headlines"):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Kompatible Produkte
    [1] => Drucktechnologie
    [2] => Druckfarben
    [3] => BCP-Tintentropfenfarbe
    [4] => Temperaturbereich bei Lagerung
    [5] => Paketgewicht
    [6] => Verpackungsabmessungen (BxTxH)
)
```

And Array two (which are the "values")

```
Array
    (
    [0] => HP Designjet 5500, 5500ps, 5000, 5000ps
    [1] => 
    [2] => Black
    [3] => 
    [4] => -40 - 60
    [5] => 230
    [6] => 114 x 36 x 264
)
```

Now I would like to combine these 2 Arrays in a 3 Array...
The array 3 looks like:

```
$data[] = array( 
    'sku' => '291',    
    '_type' => 'simple', 
    '_attribute_set' => 'Default', 
    '_product_websites' => 'base', 
    'name' => 'C4950A', 
    'manufacturer' => 'HP Inc.',    
    'meta_autogenerate' => 'yes', 
    'short_description' => 'HP 81', 
    'qty' => 2, 
);
```

And I would like to have this:

```
$data[] = array( 
    'sku' => '291',    
    '_type' => 'simple', 
    '_attribute_set' => 'Default', 
    '_product_websites' => 'base', 
    'name' => 'C4950A', 
    'manufacturer' => 'HP Inc.',    
    'meta_autogenerate' => 'yes', 
    'short_description' => 'HP 81', 
    'qty' => 2, 

    'Kompatible Produkte' => 'HP Designjet 5500, 5500ps, 5000, 5000ps',
    'Drucktechnologie' => '',
    'Druckfarben' => 'Black',
    'BCP-Tintentropfenfarbe' => '',
    'Temperaturbereich bei Lagerung' => '-40 - 60',
    'Paketgewicht' => '230',
    'Verpackungsabmessungen (BxTxH)' => '114 x 36 x 264'
);
```

The amount of values in array one and two is always the same. I thought it would be possible with "for each", but I can't find a working solution...

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily using [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function:

```
$data = array_merge($data,array_combine($arr1,$arr2));
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a foreach loop quite easily this way.

```
$a = ['a','b','c'];

$b = ['a1','b1','c1'];

$c = [
  'e' => 'e1',
  'd' => 'd1'
];

foreach($a as $key => $value){

    $c[$value] = $b[$key];

}

print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code which i have run in my system.

```
$arr1 = array("Kompatible Produkte", "Drucktechnologie", "Druckfarben", "BCP-Tintentropfenfarbe", "Temperaturbereich bei Lagerung", "Paketgewicht", "Verpackungsabmessungen (BxTxH)");
$arr2 = array("HP Designjet 5500, 5500ps, 5000, 5000ps", "", "Black", "", "-40 - 60", "230", "114 x 36 x 264");
$arr3 = array(
    'sku' => '291',
    '_type' => 'simple',
    '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
    '_product_websites' => 'base',
    'name' => 'C4950A',
    'manufacturer' => 'HP Inc.',
    'meta_autogenerate' => 'yes',
    'short_description' => 'HP 81',
    'qty' => 2,
);

$tempArr = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
$result = array_merge($arr3, $tempArr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Simplly use `array_combine` and `array_merge`.